# bs4 найти изображение на странице

Tags: python, парсер, beautiful-soup, bs4

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]На [этой странице](https://www.nike.com/ru/launch/t/womens-air-jordan-1-powder-blue-gym-red1/) мне нужно получить адрес первого изображения кроссовок.

Сначала я планировал получить `<figure>` по классу `data-qa="card-product-image-0"`, а затем получить дочерний тег `<img>`, который мне собственно и нужен, но я не могу этого сделать, поскольку если открыть полный код страницы(Ctrl+U), то адреса этого изображения там нет. И соответственно `soup.find_all("img")` не выдает это изображение в список.

Скажите, пожалуйста, каким образом я могу получить этот тег `<img>` с первого изображения кроссовок (вид сбоку)?

Comment: ну картинка находится в этом диве  <div class="carousel-card-content">
этого разве не хватит чтобы спарсить?

Answer (score 1):

Вроде бы нормально находит это изображение в карусельке. Вот его код прямо со страницы:

```
<img src="https://c.static-nike.com/a/images/t_prod_ss/w_1024,c_limit,f_auto/fd182fec-534f-4429-96e6-a21f554a76ed/womens-air-jordan-i-powder-bluegym-red-release-date.jpg" alt="Women’s Air Jordan I 'Powder Blue/Gym Red' Release Date" title="Women’s Air Jordan I 'Powder Blue/Gym Red' Release Date" class="image-component " style="opacity: 1; transition: opacity 1s ease 0s;">
```

Comment: Меня интересует программная реализация поиска этого тега либо просто алгоритм

Comment: Вся страница прогружается  только после получения объектов JS и CSS. Тут для парсинга нужен изврат. Например, отслеживать, какие запросы javascript шлёт на сервер сайта. Посмотрите статьи наподобие этой: http://www.cyberforum.ru/python/thread1540559.html